# mariadb json decode

Tags: json, regex, mariadb

I got a text column with JSON arrays.

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| code                                                                    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| []                                                                      |
| ["5020","6420"]                                                         |
| ["4645","4775"]                                                         |
| ["6820"]                                                                |
| ["2442","2511"]                                                         |
| ["4675"]                                                                |
| ["1814","6201","6203","6209","6312","6399","7022","7311","7312","7320"] |
| ["6910","6920"]                                                         |
| ["4321","4329","4652","7112"]                                           |
| ["4332","7739"]                                                         |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I need to get these codes to another table as single integer values. As soon as there are millions of records I would not like to fetch these records to php/ruby/etc for this task. I'd like to make it inside MariaDB with SQL.

The question is what could be a nice approach for such query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the first posted answer about reading table in chunks, some other possible solutions:

1) If it needs to be done once or rarely, I would go with the low-tech approach:

- select `code` into an outfile;
- run a simple `sed` (remove square brackets and replace commas with new lines, thus getting one number per row, quote marks don't matter);
- load the file into a table.

2) If you really want to stick with SQL only, there should be a procedure:

- use cursor to go through each row;
- use substring replacements to convert the array-like string `["1","2"]` into the values-like string `(1),(2)` -- it's simple, although a bit ugly;
- append the resulting string to `INSERT INTO <table name> VALUES`;
- run it as a prepared statement;

3) If you want to go fancy and experiment (assuming it's not production), try JSON functions in MariaDB 10.2, also through a procedure:

- use cursor to go through each row;
- use `JSON_LENGTH` to get a number of elements in the array;
- use a loop (e.g. `WHILE`) to `JSON_EXTRACT` each value in turn and either insert it immediately, or again build a prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

No.  The SQL code would be so messy as to be worse overall.

I would read the table in chunks of 100-1000 rows, go through the arrays to get the numbers, de-dup (in php/etc) then do `INSERT` or `INSERT IGNORE` into the target table.

Tips on chunking (aimed at `DELETE`, but adaptable for `SELECT`):  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks

Answer (score 0):

**For PHP. u can use it**

```
$re = '/\d+/m';
$str = '+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| code                                                                    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| []                                                                      |
| ["5020","6420"]                                                         |
| ["4645","4775"]                                                         |
| ["6820"]                                                                |
| ["2442","2511"]                                                         |
| ["4675"]                                                                |
| ["1814","6201","6203","6209","6312","6399","7022","7311","7312","7320"] |
| ["6910","6920"]                                                         |
| ["4321","4329","4652","7112"]                                           |
| ["4332","7739"]                                                         |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

// Print the entire match result
print_r($matches);
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5020
            [1] => 6420
            [2] => 4645
            [3] => 4775
            [4] => 6820
            [5] => 2442
            [6] => 2511
            [7] => 4675
            [8] => 1814
            [9] => 6201
            [10] => 6203
            [11] => 6209
            [12] => 6312
            [13] => 6399
            [14] => 7022
            [15] => 7311
            [16] => 7312
            [17] => 7320
            [18] => 6910
            [19] => 6920
            [20] => 4321
            [21] => 4329
            [22] => 4652
            [23] => 7112
            [24] => 4332
            [25] => 7739
        )

)
```

u should do

```
$str = Result (MYSQL JSON)
```

**Enjoy.**